# How to use dynamic buttons with array data

Tags: java, android, youtube-data-api

I am still working on my first android app and hope you can help me once more. I use the YouTube API to get all the content from my channel and create the following list:

[image]

Now my problem is I do not know how I can tell the buttons in the middle of each thumbnail to start the according video. I have the correct video ID for each element (provided in a textview on the right during troubleshooting...) but when I try to connect this information to the button onclick method it will just use the first textview content on the screen, so it is always just opening the first video => for every single button.

```
    public void jumpin(View view) {
    TextView textViewHelper = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.videoIdTester);
    String textViewHelperString = textViewHelper.getText().toString();

    Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(this, API_KEY, textViewHelperString);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

My basic problem is that the buttons are not filled with the video ID information like the textviews for example. The buttons are just created and I call the onclick method which needs the video id then which is not reachable from my perspective as soon as the list is created.

I think this is by far too complicated at the moment but I have no plan how to solve that. I can provide more code if you need it but I think this problem is more about button and api/array behaviour in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anwered by myself, using an onitemclick listener instead of the buttons ...